# Stairs-like multline

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, multline

The `multline` environment alignes the first line to the left, the last one to the right, while all the lines in between are simply centered. The result sometimes looks not satisfying, for example, when all the lines are just slightly wider that the half ot the text width.

[image: Standard multline]

What I am looking for is a tool to make it apper more "stairs-like", as in the picture below, but without adding manually chosen `\hspace{...}` into each line.

[image: Adjusted multline]

I know there are all kinds of exceptions such as lines too wide and so on, and I do not expect the solution to always make a perfect output, but there should be something that works in a "generic" case. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can set each line in a macro that spreads them out "manually" using something like `\setline[<align>]{<portion>}{<stuff>}` as defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\setline}[3][c]{\hspace*{#2\linewidth}\makebox[0pt][#1]{#3}}
\newenvironment{spreadlines}
  {\par
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
   \obeylines}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{spreadlines}
  \setline[l]{0}  {The first line is aligned to the left.}
  \setline   {.25}{The second line is (not) centred.}
  \setline   {.5} {And so is the third one.}
  \setline   {.75}{As well as the fourth --- not centred!}
  \setline[r]{1}  {The last line is aligned to the right.}
\end{spreadlines}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

It would probably be possible to determine the value `{<portion>}` automatically, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Package `mathtools` provide option `\shoveleft[<ofset>]{<part of equation>}` by which you can easy obtain stairs like `multline`:
[image]

Code based on example in mathtools manual (pp 17):

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\[
\begin{multlined}
\framebox[.65\columnwidth]{First line} \\
\shoveleft[1cm]{\framebox[.5\columnwidth]{Second line} } \\
\shoveleft[2cm]{\framebox[.5\columnwidth]{Second line} } \\
\shoveleft[3cm]{\framebox[.5\columnwidth]{Second line} } \\
\framebox[.65\columnwidth]{Last line}
\end{multlined}
\]
    \end{document}
```